# How to make simple async action method returning content return actual content and not type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await

here is a very simply MVC asynchronous action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ContentResult> Trial()
    {
        ContentResult contentResult = await new Task<ContentResult>(()=>new ContentResult{Content="Hi"});
        return contentResult;
    }
```

I would expect a post to this action to respond with the content "Hi".  But it does not.  It responds with the content "System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Web.Mvc.ContentResult]".

Here is the full response:

```
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
    Pragma: no-cache
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    Content-Encoding: gzip
    Expires: -1
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
    X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge
    Date: Mon, 23 Nov 2020 17:02:37 GMT
    Content-Length: 166
    
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Web.Mvc.ContentResult]
```

Would love some insights into why, and how to get the content "Hi" as expected, using an Async function.  Thanks.

Comment: Because you are creating a Task<> object, and not the result of executing the task.

Comment: Neil got the point ... you shoul use `Task.Run` not `new Task`

Comment: This can happen if you're using a very old version of MVC. You must be running (at least) ASP.NET 4.5 on .NET Framework 4.5 for `Task`-returning action method to work.

Comment: Thanks.  @StephenCleary is exactly right.  This is an old project still pointing to MVC version 4.0.  Thanks.  (Same behavior with `Task.Run` and with `new Task`).

Comment: @StephanG It will be good if you mark Stephen Cleary response as answer. Will help others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can happen if you're using a very old version of MVC. You must be running (at least) ASP.NET 4.5 on .NET Framework 4.5 for Task-returning action method to work. `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` *does not work* for ASP.NET projects.

If you have .NET Framework 4.5 or newer on your web servers, you can upgrade your project to ASP.NET 4.5. After upgrading, you [*must* turn off "quirks mode" for `async` to work properly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net). I prefer to do this by [setting `httpRuntime.targetFramework` in your `web.config` to `4.5`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework/) (or whatever version you upgrade to).